# Can I update package dependencies in Arch Linux?

Tags: dependencies, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I've installed shellcheck on Arch and tried to use, but it thrown error:

```
shellcheck: error while loading shared libraries: libHSaeson-1.5.4.1-A0L815KAfIF5MogEzEmc2-ghc8.10.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed `haskell-aeson`, but it continued to throw:

```
shellcheck: error while loading shared libraries: libHStime-compat-1.9.4-KktNpyhBIj4KuEl1uK3ffn-ghc8.10.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But I noticed that package `haskell-time-compat` is already installed:

```
$ pacman -Q haskell-time-compat
haskell-time-compat 1.9.3-23
```

And it doesn't have right version, so, I don't want to update entire system now or update all dependencies manually, so is there any way to update package with it's dependencies on Arch?

Comment: Since Arch's update strategy are rolling releases, you should update your entire system by all means. Most problems people encounter with package dependencies are caused by incompatible library versions. Try updating your whole system before messing with single updates by hand. Even the updated packages might rely on newer package versions as well.